# How to change a flask config variable at runtime when running with gunicorn

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app running with Gunicorn. In my app.config, I have a field "key" that I would like to change dynamically without restarting the app.

I was able to do this locally without gunicorn i.e change the value of app.config["key"].
But when using gunicorn the key gets back to it's original value after each request.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure understand what you really mean, http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload. You wanna do a auto-restart?

Comment: Not an auto-restart. So the key is rotated automatically monthly and is written to a file. The key is an IAM key for accessing  amazon S3.

At app startup, I have app.config["key"] = default_value.

I tried this app.config["key"] = new_key_from_file whenever there was a new change in the key

Comment: Can you produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your application is most likely running in several thread/processes so you would need to change all of them. Personally I think the best way to solve this issue is to use a shared caching system such as redis/memcache. If it changes it shouldn't be in a config imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must reload the app, because `gunicorn` handle workers even restarting them after `max_requests` reached.

It is possible to update a config file and [reload `gunicorn` gracefully](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#server-stuff) with a `HUP` signal, without missing requests.

```
$ kill -HUP masterpid
```

If it is a shared key, maybe you want a shared repository, like a database or `etcd`. Change the value there, your app get the value and everything works great.

Comment: Why 2 downvotes after 2 years? Maybe something changed. Please, the next one downvoting this answer, comment the reason.